# Paypal MPL iOS error

Tags: ios, paypal

I am trying to integrate the PayPal MPL library into an iOS app. I have a UIViewController that is creating the PayPal button like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [PayPal initializeWithAppID:SANDBOX_API_KEY
             forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];

    UIButton* paypalButton = [[PayPal getPayPalInst] getPayButtonWithTarget:self andAction:@selector(checkoutPayment) andButtonType:BUTTON_294x43];
    [self.view addSubview:paypalButton];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The app prints the following error message to the console a second or so after opening the ViewController.

```
Checking Error********************
Posting Error: 2147483647
DEVELOPER ERROR: This app isn’t using a supported version of the PayPal library.
```

I can't find anything about this error on Google, so here I am. Any ideas on how to fix it?

I am using xcode 4.5 and iOS 6 beta to test, and the 1_5_5_070_iPhone_DevelopersPackage version of the MPL library (the latest one on the website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Bundle Version in the Info.plist used alphanumeric characters. It seems the PayPal library reads it and expects it to be a number.

Comment: hey i didnt get. can u plz elaborate in detail..  Thanx

Comment: Currently my bundle version is 1.0.

Comment: Try changing it to 1 instead of 1.0 (the . confuses paypal I think, it is trying to turn 1.0 into an integer)

Answer (score 3):

I also noticed that you have to have "bundle display name" in your info.plist
Without it you will get posting error as well

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is very old, but there is one more requirement. It took me a while to find out. It must not be a very big integer. I've had a version string that was something like 20141014122113 (or YMdHms) and that also set this off. After having it shortened to 20141014 everything started working. So these appear to be the rules:

1. You must have a bundle display name
2. Just digits in build number
3. Build number must not be too long